# C# - ListBox / ListView to support both data binding and thumbnails

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a C# Windows Forms Application, I want a list control which supports two features:

1. ListView-style **Thumbnail display**. ListView allows you to bind it to an ImageList, but ListBox doesn't support thumbnails.
2. **Binding data** - ListBox allows you to bind a list of 'object' using the DataSource property. However all I need is to be able to bind data to each item's caption and an ID value so that appropriate processing can be done based on whichever item was clicked. Unfortunately, ListView doesn't have a feature like this as far as I know.

Is there a straightforward solution? Preferably not using trial versions of additional downloadable products. A commonly-used NuGet package would be fine.

Comment: Winforms? WPF? Please add appropriate tags and be more specific in your question.

Comment: Winforms, I'm guessing. I feel like that's a bit of a cut and paste response on your part - I can only provide the information I have. The question can't be more specific - I want to display list items as thumbnails and bind a list of 'object's - or possibly strings along with IDs, like I said.

Comment: You maybe want to use the Telerik [RadListControl](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/dropdown-listcontrol-and-checkeddropdownlist/listcontrol/listcontrol)? (This is a commercial UI library).

Comment: That does seem to provide the features I was looking for, but it seems like a commercial library with a trial version - also it doesn't seem too straightforward to download a whole library just to use one control. I wanted thumbnails in the style supported by ListView. I should make the question more specific as Daniel suggested, after all. Sorry I wasn't too helpful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own `ThumbnailListBox` by deriving it from `ListBox`:

```
public class ThumbnailListBox : ListBox
{
    public ThumbnailListBox()
    {
        DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        ItemHeight = 32;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then you must override `OnDrawItem` and draw your stuff. Note that you have to draw the text as well.

```
protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    if (e.Index >= 0 && e.Index < Items.Count) {
        var item = (MyItemType)Items[e.Index];
        StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
        stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
        stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        var textRect = e.Bounds;
        textRect.X += 35;
        textRect.Width -= 35;
        using (var textBrush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)) {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, Font, textBrush, textRect, stringFormat);
        }
        Image img = item.GetThumbnail();
        if (img != null) {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 1, 1);
        }
    }
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

In this example I assume that you are using Object-Binding to objects of a type `MyItemType`.

---

If you have thumbnails of different sizes, you can set the `DrawMode` to `DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable` and then override `OnMeasureItem` where you can specify a different height for every item.

```
protected override void OnMeasureItem(MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index >= 0 && e.Index < Items.Count) {
        var item = (MyItemType)Items[e.Index];
        e.ItemHeight = Math.Max(15, item.GetThumbnailHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and see how it goes. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done in Blend for VS. 
In Blend click on properties for the ListBox.
Click on the Items Property.
On the bottom screen of the popup to the left of the "Add" button select other type.
type image into the search textBox provided. Select image.
On the image select source and add desired picture. The picture can also be added in C# by changing its Source property. I hope this helps.

Comment: This is a solution for anyone using Blend or who is happy to reinstall Visual Studio on their computer(s) to get a trial version of Blend. I feel bad not accepting this - but I was looking for something which didn't involve additional downloads - or at least is a commonly used NuGet package. Something like subclassing a ListView and overriding one or two of its methods? Would that work?

Comment: To avoid any downloads, simply: create a class that contains each of the data items including the image that you would like the listBox to present.

Comment: Create a list that contains this class assign this list as the ItemsSource of the ListBox. ListBox.ItemsSource = myItemsList.